# DatePicker default date in other format

Tags: c#, wpf, datepicker

I have a WPF window with a DatePicket controller.
I would like to show the current date not the "Show Calendar" text.

I used this reference

```
xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
```

and this code

```
<DatePicker x:Name="DatePicker1" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" SelectedDate="{x:Reference sys:DateTime.Now}">
```

It works fine but I would like to change the date format like this: yyyy. mm. dd.
How can I do this?

Comment: try FormatString property

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do so by changing the template of the date picker to modify the underlying textbox.  Please see example below:

```
<DatePicker SelectedDate="{x:Static sys:DateTime.Now}">
   <DatePicker.Resources>
      <Style TargetType="DatePickerTextBox">
         <Setter Property="Control.Template">
            <Setter.Value>
               <ControlTemplate>
                  <TextBox x:Name="PART_TextBox"
                     Text="{Binding Path=SelectedDate, StringFormat={}{0:yyyy.MM.dd}, 
                     RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DatePicker}}}" />
               </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
         </Setter>
      </Style>
   </DatePicker.Resources>
</DatePicker>
```

I changed `SelectedDate="{x:Static sys:DateTime.Now}"` from  `x:Reference` to `x:Static` to get it working when testing.

Result:
[image]

BTW, if you want to re-use this code for multiple datepickers then you can just copy the XAML for the `<Style></Style>` tags (and everything within) and place that into your App.xaml under `<Application.Resources>` and the style/format will be applied to all of the date pickers.

I found the above code [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/e55103a5-21df-4c59-b7b3-7e388ef024c9/wpf-datepicker-selecteddate-binding-format?forum=wpf).

Answer (score 0):

You will need to specify the format as shown below, Below is example of text block:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Source={x:Static system:DateTime.Now}, StringFormat=Date: {0:yyyy.MM.dd}}" />
```

For DatePicker, you will have to set the control template to modify the TextBlock.  Below is the sample code from:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type DatePickerTextBox}">
 <Setter Property="Control.Template">
  <Setter.Value>
   <ControlTemplate>
    <TextBox x:Name="PART_TextBox"
     Text="{Binding Path=SelectedDate, StringFormat='dd MM yyyy', 
     RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DatePicker}}}" />
   </ControlTemplate>
  </Setter.Value>
 </Setter>
</Style>
```

You can use any standard DateTime format here.  Hope this helps.